# Installing Windows Server AppFabric

Tags: appfabric, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install Windows Server AppFabric using Web Platform Installer on my testing Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition. Although I have SQL Server (Developer Edition) installed on the server, WPI is still "insisting" that I need SQL Server Express, and I don't have option to change that.

The question is: how can I tell the setup that I already have SQL Server and don't need the Express Edition? The same goes when I go production; I'll have my SQL Server on separate server, so how can I tell AppFabric what SQL Server it need to connect to, as well as preventing SQL Server Express Edition from being installed.

P.S. I'm intending to use AppFabric for caching only and only on a single server; i.e. no WCF and WF fancy stuff or distributed cache.

Thanks

TheBlueSky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that WPI isn't your best bet in this instance - you can download the standalone installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2). Also, although Web PI insists on installing SQL Sexpress, there's no requirement for you atually *use* it :-) - I have the same setup as you with SQL Server Developer installed, which is what I use for my AppFabric setup.

Once AppFabric is installed you can select a SQL Server to use when you run the configuration wizard:
[image]

Comment: +1. We had the same problem; this solution worked for us a while back.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as the limitation comes from PI and AppFabric setup is capable of handling my requirement.